# Bittrex API 3 minute delay

Tags: api, bittrex

I'm noticing that the Bittrex API (both v1.1 and v2.0) have a 3 to 4 minute delay when getting data, i.e. GetLatestTick:
https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/market/GetLatestTick?marketName=BTC-NEO&tickInterval=hour

So if you make a request say at 8:00PM, it will not bring the 7:00 to 8:00PM candle data until 8:03PM, some times 8:04PM ...

I thought about constructing my own candles querying the API every few seconds with /getticker - but for a few cryptos it will get lengthy and might get banned for the amount of requests per second ...

Anyone knows any other method to get candle data sooner?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to get?

Comment: Candles for the last hour for a number of currencies (/GetLatestTick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the same. I am afraid that we have to live with it since even on bittrex website charts are delayed by 3 minutes approximately. You can see that if you get the 1-minute chart plotted. Market history is on time though. If you need this sort of speed, you could build a script to catch ticks from market history list.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this delay as well. There can be up to four-minutes of delay on the Bittrex API. When looking at the parabolic SAR, I have found that this data can be behind by up to three ticks of the SAR. To solve the problem, I used [cluedex.com](https://www.cluedex.com/product/api/ohlcv-candle-api) which provides a premium API for this data. There is no delay and I have found that the SAR metric that I calculate is much faster with this data, which means I can place trades ahead of the trend.